# Does ArcGIS Pro create Blank project always open Project View now?

Tags: arcgis-pro

Prior to ArcGIS Pro 1.4 my recollection is that when choosing to create a Blank project the Project View did not open - see below for the old behaviour where I have the Contents and Project Panes open but, if closed and the project saved, then they do not open for the next Blank project that is created.  This old behaviour is the same as that seen in the Create a project Help's [Tutorial summary video](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/create-a-project.htm).

[image]

At ArcGIS Pro 1.4 creating a new Blank project **always** has the Project View open.

[image]

If this change in behaviour is reproducible between versions, then is it considered to be an enhancement or a minor bug?

Comment: Its all a matter of perspective: bug, enhancement, etc. Regardless of what you want to call it, it was an intentional change.

Comment: @KHibma Are you able to share what drove it?  I use the Project Pane extensively but have found negligible use for the Project View. I don't want to overlook functionality that could aid my workflows.

Comment: I'm not on that team, so I'm not privy to the 'why' decisions. I just know it was changed at some point in the 1.4 development cycle as I noticed one day it opened a new project like that vs. the empty app.

Comment: I would be happy to accept an answer based on your two comments.  There's no need for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @KHibma:

> Its all a matter of perspective: bug, enhancement, etc. Regardless of
>   what you want to call it, it was an intentional change.

and:

> I'm not on that team, so I'm not privy to the 'why' decisions. I just
>   know it was changed at some point in the 1.4 development cycle as I
>   noticed one day it opened a new project like that vs. the empty app.